# App closed when going to the background on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, background-process, galaxy

I am developing a rather normal-resource-usage app (about 19-22 MB on the Galaxy S3, so it can definitely handle it), and one of its "features" is to show the info of a contact, by using the next code:

```
public static Intent createIntentForContact(final String contactKey) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, contactKey);
    intent.setData(uri);
    return intent;
}

    ...
    startActivity(createIntentForContact(...)) ;
```

Everything works fine as long as I stay on the app.

If, however, I press on home while the app shows the info of the device contact, and then return to the app, and then I press back, the app restarts itself.

I've tested this code on a totally new project, but it worked totally fine there. I've also tested it on a Galaxy S2, and it worked totally fine there as well. I've checked the developers category in the settings, and nothing special is ticked there.

How could such a thing occur? 
The app doesn't take much memory, so why was it closed, and why wasn't it closed together with the contact info screen (since I didn't add any flags for it)?

---

EDIT: I've noticed in the logs, that there are some logs related to roboguice which might be the reason for this problem. Here are the logs:

01-07 11:40:00.610: W

```
/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856): Could not load Finalizer in its own class loader. Loading Finalizer in the current class loader instead. As a result, you will not be able to garbage collect this class loader. To support reclaiming this class loader, either resolve the underlying issue, or move Google Collections to your system class path.
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856): java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Finalizer.class
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.getBaseUrl(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:269)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.loadFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:253)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.loadFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:175)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.<clinit>(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:100)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$QueueHolder.<clinit>(MapMaker.java:787)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$WeakEntry.<init>(MapMaker.java:946)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$Strength$1.newEntry(MapMaker.java:312)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.newEntry(MapMaker.java:498)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.newEntry(MapMaker.java:419)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2029)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.hasAnnotations(Annotations.java:116)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.isBindingAnnotation(Annotations.java:180)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.Key.ensureIsBindingAnnotation(Key.java:366)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:338)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:272)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingBuilder.annotatedWithInternal(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:82)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstantBindingBuilderImpl.annotatedWith(ConstantBindingBuilderImpl.java:49)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:117)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:78)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:83)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:139)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.syncme.modules.SyncMEApplication.onCreate(SyncMEApplication.java:41)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1003)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4228)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-07 11:40:00.610: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(6856):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is there any messages in the LogCat?
As to why this happens on the S3, but not on the S2, could be differences in the Android version. I think Google changed the Contact API earlier - this could have something to do with this.

Comment: You should compare manifest files of your work app and new test app. There is something different in activity handling. May be related to Android version, so please add this info into the question.

Comment: seems like a roboguice error. will write down the logs hoping someone would understand what is going on .

Comment: also , the manifest doesn't have any special thing about the activity . only those : android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"  , android:screenOrientation="portrait"